# Link inside button is clickable, but not the button itself

Tags: html, css

I have a button in which there is a link. When I mouseover the button, the cursor changes, but clicking the button doesn't do anything. Instead I have to click the link inside. How can I reformat my code, so that the button itself is clickable and not just the link inside of it?

```
<button class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" style="margin:30px;" >
       <a href="https://www.google.com/"></a>
</button>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Anchors can't be children of buttons. If you want your anchor to look like a button, use CSS

Comment: to continue eleborationg the above comment: a `<button>` is a trigger to fire a script while an `<a>nchor` redirects to another resource. A button is not just a visual element and not to be mistake as anything that just looks like a button. As already said it is soley a semantic tag that is used as script trigger

Comment: You can also make the button to change `location.href` on click but it's not recommended

Comment: <a href="https://www.google.com/">
<button class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" style="margin:30px;" >
</button>
</a>

Comment: @dita the code you have given is not valid HTML. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a An anchor element cannot have interactive content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Onclick button event.

```html
 <button onclick="window.location.href='https://www.google.com/'"></button>
```

Answer (score -3):

So basically, it's not getting you anywhere simply because there is no content (text, icon, image, etc) within the anchor tag to click on.

Try the code below and you should be taken to the link specified in the "href" attribute of the anchor tag.

`<button class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" style="margin: 30px;" > <a href="https://www.google.com/" style="text-decoration: none;">Search on Google</a> </button>`

Comment: still invalid. An anchor can't be a child of a button. See the comments

Comment: That's semantically quite correct. But the above answer was given based on the context of the code provided by the original question. In essence, either of an anchor tag or a button can solve the problem with a little of CSS.